# Spark Structured Streaming metrics: Why process rate can be greater than input rate?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

**How come the process rate can be greater than the input rate?**

**From my understanding, process rate is the rate by which spark can process arriving data, ie, the process capacity.** If so, the process rate must be on average lower or equal to the input rate. If it is lower, we know we need more processing power, or rethink about trigger time.

I am basing my understanding on [this blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/29/a-look-at-the-new-structured-streaming-ui-in-apache-spark-3-0.html) and common sense, but I might be wrong. I looking for the formal formula in the source code while writing this question, as well.

This is an example where the process rate is constantly greater than the input rate:

[image: Process rate > Input rate]

You can see that on averege we have 200-300 records being processed per sec, whereas we have 80-120 records arriving per sec.

Setup background: Spark 3.x reading from Kafka and writing to Delta.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Process rate more than input rate could mean its processing much faster than input rate. i.e it could process 300-400 per sec although event rate is 100 per sec. For ex: lets say ~100 per sec is the input rate and spark is able to  process 100 records within half a sec than it means it can process 100 more in the next half of the sec and on an average this would lead to ~200 process rate.

In screenshot attached it could be interpreted as
It can process ~3000 records within each batch(~200*~15s) with 15s processing time for each batch (based on ~15000 ms seen in latency chart) but its processing around ~1000 records within each batch with 15s processing time.

Comment: Thanks, @Vindhya G. I see what you say, but do you know where we can see the formal calculation to confirm it? Didn't find it in the source code for now.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/ui/StreamingQueryStatisticsPage.scala#L389
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/bbdbe0f734c95ebc80facf74d00a78866e444128/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/ProgressReporter.scala#L193

Comment: Based on the two links above of the code i think we can come to same conclusion as above.